# centring an image ontop of another one in python(PIL), then hiding one inside the other

Tags: python, image, watermark

The task is to make two functions one that embeds a grayscale image inside a RGB one. The second then shows the hidden "watermark". I've completed the task( there is 15 tests the code must pass I passed them all :D), but I want to tidy up my code if possible. I have been told that I could have used the crop function to centre the water mark on top of the photo(I couldn't work out how to do this) instead I used math logic.

```
from PIL import Image
#function for embedding the watermark
def add_watermark(clean_file, watermark_file):

#if the files are not compatible
#or doesn't exist end the function
try:
    clean_photo = Image.open(clean_file)
    watermark_photo = Image.open(watermark_file)
except:
    return False

#the images pixels tuple values are attained
clean_photo_size = clean_photo.size
watermark_photo_size = watermark_photo.size

# .load  was used to return a pixel access object
# that can be used to read and modify pixels
#for both images 
photo_array = clean_photo.load()
watermark_array = watermark_photo.load()

#centring the watermarked image on the photo
start_x_coord=int((clean_photo_size[0]-watermark_photo_size[0])/2)
start_y_coord=int((clean_photo_size[1]-watermark_photo_size[1])/2)

#for the pixels that share the same position as the pixels in the
#watermark, manipulate their RGB tuple value to include the watermarks
#greyscale value as part of the original RGB tuple
for line in range(watermark_photo_size[0]):
    for rank in range(watermark_photo_size[1]):
         photo_array [(start_x_coord+line),\
                (start_y_coord+rank)]\
                =(int(((photo_array [(start_x_coord+line),\
                                     (start_y_coord+rank)][0]/10)*10)\
                      +((watermark_array[line,rank]/100)%10)),\
                  int(((photo_array [(start_x_coord+line),\
                                     (start_y_coord+rank)]\
                        [1]/10)*10)+((watermark_array[line,rank]/10)%10)),\
                  int(((photo_array [(start_x_coord+line),\
                                     (start_y_coord+rank)][2]/10)*10)\
                      +(watermark_array[line,rank]%10)))

#create a new file name with _X at the end 
new_File_Name = clean_file[:-4]+"_X"+clean_file[-4:]

#create a new file
clean_photo.save(new_File_Name)

#return true for the test
return True
```

I tried to make this post spelling and grammar correct, but I have been awake for 20 hours now so I apologize if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can center an image watermark on top of another image:

## NOTE: Image and ImageEnhance require the PIL system library to be installed to the Python runtime

```
import os 
from os.path import join, exists
import shutil
import Image

class BatchWatermark:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []


    def process(self, infolder, outfolder, watermarkImage):
        if not exists(infolder):
            print("Input folder '" + infolder + "' does not exist")
            raise Exception("Input folder '" + infolder + "' does not exist")
        #if exists(outfolder):
        #    shutil.rmtree(outfolder)

        watermark = Image.open(watermarkImage)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(infolder):
            for name in files:    
                try:
                    im = Image.open(join(root, name))
                    if im.mode != 'RGBA':
                        im = im.convert('RGBA')
                        layer = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))

                        wm_x, wm_y = watermark.size[0], watermark.size[1]
                        x = (im.size[0] - wm_x)/2
                        y = (im.size[1] - wm_y)/2
                        position = (x, y)
                        layer.paste(watermark, position)
                        if not exists(outfolder):
                            os.makedirs(outfolder)
                        Image.composite(layer, im, layer).save(join(outfolder, name))
                        print "Watermark added to image file '" + outfolder + "/" + name + "'";
                except Exception, (msg):
                    print msg
```